# Global function header and implementation

Tags: c++

how can I divide the header and implementation of a global function?

My way is:

split.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void split(const string s, const string c);
```

split.cpp

```
#include "split.h"

void split(const string& s, const string& c){
...
}
```

main.cpp

```
// main.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "split.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<string> v;
    string s = "The;;woraaald;;is;;not;;enoaaaugh";
    string c = " aaa ;; ccc";
    split(s,c);

    return 0;
}
```

And errors are:

Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   ...\split.h 8

Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 's'   ...\split.h 8

How can I solve this problem? thx

Comment: Classes in the standard library are in the `std::` namespace. Do not use `using namespace` in the header file, fully qualify the name. For consistency, perhaps try to rid yourself of that habit in source files as well.

Comment: The second error is caused by `string` which needs to be `std::string` (unless you specify `using std::string;`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In header file use std:: namespace qualifier - std::string

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is, you are missing the 'std::' namespace qualifier in split.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void split(const std::string s, const std::string c);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the header file, you have to give the fully qualified name `std::string`. In the source files, you can add `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;` and then just spell it `string`.

Also, you've declared the function taking arguments by value, but defined it taking arguments by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either forgot to put `using std::string;` before split declaration or use `std::string const&` as split parameter declarations.

Also split declaration mismatch from split definition `string const` vs `string const&`